# Django context processor doesn't display new context values in template

Tags: python, django

EDIT: Updated now that I've narrowed down the problem to the context processor variable not being available to a template that I'm loading with a custom tag.

I'm using Django 1.11 and this is my first time trying to use a custom context processor.

The problem is that the context variable I'm supposed to be adding from the context processor does not return anything from within a template loaded from a custom tag. I don't receive any errors.

So below {{ testcontext }} should return "IT WORKED!" and does so in my base.html template, but returns nothing in the template loaded with @register.inclusion_tag().

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'appname.context_processors.test_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

context_processors.py:

```
def test_context(request):
    return {'testcontext': 'TEST WORKED!'}
```

tags.py

```
from django import template

from appname.models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('template.html')
def load_category(selected_slug=None):
    return {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'selected':selected_slug,
    }
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from appname.models import MyModel

class MyView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from appname.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

template.html

```
{{ testcontext }}
```

Comment: It seems to code is correct. You might type the wrong  path of function definition

Comment: Your code looks ok. Use the [`{% debug %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) template tag or the django debug toolbar to check the template context to make sure you are using the correct variable in the context.

Comment: `MyView` doesn't specify that it uses the template `template.html`. Are you sure it uses the correct template?

Comment: You should check the template without the processor. What happens if you define testcontext directly in the view's `get_context_data` method?

Comment: Using {% debug %}, I verified that my context variable definitely isn't assigned. Shouldn't a context variable added by a context processor be available to all templates provided a RequestContext has been included in the view? Also, I'm pretty sure I have the right path to context_processors.py because it will execute a print() statement on every page refresh, and it will throw an error if the path is wrong.

Comment: OK so I omitted a detail that turns out to make all the difference. The template file I was trying to use the context variable in is loaded via a custom tag using the @register.inclusion_tag('template.html') decorator. I discovered that when I use {{ testcontext }} in my base.html template it works as it should. So now how do I get the testcontext variable to work in a template file loaded via @register.inclusion_tag? Or am I going about this wrong altogether? Original question updated with my tags.py.

Answer (score 4):

So the problem was in my custom tag not carrying over the context when loading template.html. So the below code fixes it and my variable from the context processor is now working as expected.

tags.py

```
from django import template

from appname.models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
def load_category(context,selected_slug=None):
    return {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'selected': selected_slug,
        'testcontext': context['testcontext'] 
    }
```